# Java Properties file across multiple programs

Tags: java

So I have to figure out how to use a single .properties file across 7 different executable jar files that all eventually call one another in some way shape or form. I'm compiling with ant to a dist folder and I will put the properties file in that folder but I want to know if once I start the first program if it is possible to access the buffered properties file from the other 6 programs?

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("example.properties"));
properties.load(stream);
stream.close();
String sprache = properties.getProperty("lang");
```

But I'm not sure how to access that same buffer from program 1 to program 2?

Edit: I guess I im hoping there is a way to share that buffer but in theory I could just load an instance of the properties file into each of the jar files.

Comment: Do all programs run simultaneously? Do they only read the file or do they modify the properties? If they modify the file, is it for synching reasons? Maybe a socket connection between the programs would work for synching data.

Comment: All the programs do run simultaneously and they all run on the same machine and even from the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the programs run in separate VMs, you cannot access objects of one program from the other, unless you use some inter-process communications (IPC) functionality (shared cache, socket communication, etc.), but implementing such functionality is much more complex (and even slower) than simply re-reading the properties file in each program.

Comment: Alright, seems to be the simplest solution. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

7 executable jars will share 7 different JVM processes when running, so the normal (or is that sane?) answer is: no. Now if you are willing to run a small server app, you could use RMI to synchronize between them. However, at that point you're starting to run into the question of why they're not EJBs running in a container where the resource can be shared.